# Algorithm to find most efficient usage of resources

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm trying to find an algorithm that will find the most optimal use of a resource.

Example:

**List_1** has **3 pins** that can be placed at **point_a OR point_c**

**List_2** has **1 pin** that can be placed at **point_c**

**List_3** has **2 pins** that can be placed at **point_b OR point_c**

**List_4** has **2 pins** that can be placed at **point_a**

I'm trying to find the least number of **points** that I can use to satisfy all **4 lists**.
So, in the above example, I would only need **point_a and point_c** as **point_b** pins can also be place at **point_c**.

The data is placed in different lists but the lists are not sorted in any order and the points inside the list are also not sorted in any order.

Pins are a given value. All the pins have to be placed at some point. I'm trying to minimize the number of points used totally.

Comment: What is the significance of the number of pins? Are you just trying to minimise the number of points?

Comment: pins are a given value. All the pins have to be placed at some point. 
Yep, I'm trying to minimize the number of points used totally.

Comment: So the number of pins doesn't actually affect the solution?

Comment: Well not quite. The number of pins will impact the optimization.

List_1 has 3 pins that can be placed at point_a OR point_b

List_2 has 100 pin that can be placed at point_a


if there is a list with 100 pins and has to be placed at point_a, then you will only need point_a for all 103 pins above as an optimal solution instead of 100 at point_a and 3 at point_b

Comment: But regardless of the number of pins, in that second example `{a}` is a hitting set, `{b}` isn't, and `{a,b}` is a hitting set but it's bigger than `{a}`. So you would still pick just point `a` even if the numbers of pins were wildly different, surely?

Comment: I suppose so. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classical problem called the [minimum hitting set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Hitting_set_formulation) problem. You have a number of sets, and you want to construct a set of minimal size which "hits" all of them.

In your example, there are 4 sets of points `{a,c}`, `{c}`, `{b,c}` and `{a}`, and the minimum hitting set is `{a,c}`. It is a "hitting set" because it has at least one point in common with each of the four input sets; it is minimal because there is no hitting set smaller than 2 points. (It's pure coincidence that the solution happens to equal one of the input sets; that won't be true in general.)

The minimum hitting set problem is "NP-hard", meaning there is no known algorithm which gives an exact answer and also scales well to larger instances of the problem.

- If you need the true minimum, you won't do much better than some kind of [backtracking search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking).
- If an approximate answer is good enough, then there are various heuristics or approximation algorithms. The simplest option is a greedy algorithm, which keeps choosing the point which "hits" the most sets that aren't hit yet, until all the sets are hit. If that doesn't give good enough results, you will have to investigate for yourself.

The minimum hitting set problem is dual to the [minimum set cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) problem, so any minimum set cover algorithm or heuristic can also be adapted to your problem.